# What are the mobility advantages to biped humanoid mecha relative to earth terrain?

Tags: technology, physics

As the majority or popular depiction of mecha, biped and some degree humanoid mecha is the most prominent one. Will they serve an actual mobility advantage relative to various terrain in earth when they are in combat? If so what kind of terrain that serves as the best or the worst potential for biped mecha mobility?

Comment: Have you checked the other questions about mecha? There's a lot, and some of the answers will probably answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think that [multi-legged mecha](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SpiderTank) or [armless mecha](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WalkingTank) are quite popular these days, so I'd question your question.

A biped with arms would be interesting for combat engineering units, but not for hand-to-hand combat.